# Volley give me only: onErrorResponse

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I start to work with volley and when i try to make a post request it give me only errore.
Can you guys tell me when im wrong?
Im working on the Android side of the project with VolleyLibrary.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText etUsername;
private EditText etPassword;
private Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Login();
        }
    });
}

private void Login(){

    String url = "http://myapies.youcantwatch.it/loginuser_module";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if(!response.trim().equals("errors")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoggedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Fallito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La chiamata non è andata a buon fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("firstName","adkdmadm");
            params.put("password","asdasdjn");
            params.put("secretKey","dlwdmkemd3d455");
            params.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("passwordasdad", etPassword.getText().toString().trim());
            return super.getParams();
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: The site can’t be reached if thats the site you are actually using..

Comment: That is a placeholder, they said me to dont post the real link, by the way the link where i work is working fine. this is the Json it give me when i make the request
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Missing required parameters",
            "name": "ERROR_MISSING_REQUEST_ARG",
            "at": "Required Parameters: user, password, secretKey, username_utente, password_utente"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: i thought so....

Answer (score 0):

Replace StringRequest->JSONObjectRequest and check.
Pass request parameters in JSONObject, not in the header,
only pass Content-Type->application/json in header.

Answer (score 0):

change volley to another libs  like retrofit volley long time not updated